# analyse .core file generated from a load test on resin

Tags: linux, gdb, load-testing, crash-dumps, coredump

I am having a load test run on a linux machine which is generating huge .core files.
    My question is how do I analyse these. GDB is an option but would it mean to start the load test from inside GDB.
    Is there other tool which can be used?

Comment: GDB can load core files after a crash, you don't have to run the program in GDB.

Comment: could you please  tell the command used for loading .core files (without running the program) ?

Answer (score 0):

hopefully you are running your debug version of the binary, then after a core dump, you can just do

```
 $ gdb <Your_binary> <core_dump_file>
 (gdb) bt
```

then you can examine the stack trace.